# Why is the z =z' when using Milne-Thomson Method for determining a holomorphic function?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

When we use Milne-Thomson method, we substitute $x$ and $y$ with $\frac{z+z^*}2$ and $\frac{z-z^*}{2i}$. This gives us...

$f(z) = u(x,y) + iv(x,y) = u(\frac{z+z^*}2, \frac{z-z^*}{2i}) + i v(\frac{z+z^*}2, \frac{z-z^*}{2i})$

$z^*$ represents the conjugate of $z$.

We then proceed to say that for the above relation $z=z^*$.

Why did we we do that? And how can we say that? I mean, this seems like a massive over-simplification.

Comment: The Milne Thomson method (and its proof) for determining an analytic function from its real part has been taken up again in this question:   https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2908514/milne-thomson-method-proof/2911672#2911672

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bit of trickery involved in that you start sticking complex arguments into the functions $u$ and $v$. But suppose that this is not a problem, meaning $x$ and $y$ can be treated as complex variables. You are then looking at the equation

$$
f(x+i y) = u(x,y) + i v(x,y)
$$

over the complex numbers. You see that the left-hand side only depends on the linear combination of $x$ and $y$, and a change of variables

$$
z = x + i y, w = x - i y
$$

produces an expression where the l.h.s. is independent of $w$:

$$
f(z) = u((z+w)/2,(z-w)/2i) + i v((z+w)/2,(z-w)/2i)
$$

That means in particular that the r.h.s. holds whatever the choice of $w$. To make the expression as simple as possible, one can pick $w = z$:

$$
f(z) = u(z,0) + i v(z,0)
$$

This works only because it was assumed that $f$ is a holomorphic function: If not, the l.h.s. depends on $x - i y = w$ as well.

Comment: So, is it like that when we take z = w, we are actually compensating for taking x and y as complex variables?

Comment: And I'm sorry but I don't quite understand what you mean when you say"That means in particular that the r.h.s holds whatever the choice of w". Isn't w dependant on z?

Comment: Not really, no. You take $w = z$ to eliminate $z$ from the second argument of $u$/$v$ entirely.

Comment: It's not dependent (that's why I called it $w$ here and not $z^*$ as usual). You start with 2 independent variables $x$ and $y$, and after the change of variables, you have of course again 2 independent variables, $z$ and $w$. Try and think about the whole argument considering $x$ and $y$ not as the real components of $z$, but two independent variables.

Comment: Oh, so z and w are just the sum and difference of a complex number and iota times another complex number?

Comment: One last question. How does f being holomorphic help our case?

Comment: Yes. You see that the l.h.s. depends only on the combination $x+iy$, so you might try a change of variables $z=x+iy$, but you need a second independent variable, for which you pick $w=x−iy$ (although the choice does not matter as long as it is well-defined). Again, it's important that $f$ is holomorphic, or there would be a dependency on $x−iy = w$ on the l.h.s. as well, and you could no longer pick $w$ freely.

Comment: If it is not analytic, how do you say that the function will depend on the new variable 'w'? What has analyticity got to do with Dependency on a variable and it's conjugate.